# setInterval with an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, setinterval

I'd like to use the `setInterval` function in `jQuery` in order to create an alert with the content of one array every 4 seconds. However my alerts show all the values of my array within a short amount of time and it stops for 4 seconds after having displayed all the values.

```
$.each(['html5', 'EDM', 'Coca Cola', 'creativity'], function(id,value) {
    setInterval(function(){
        alert(value);
    }, 4000);
});
```

In this case, I'd like to display something like : *Alert('html5') - 4 seconds - Alert('EDM') - 4 seconds - Alert('Coca Cola') - 4 seconds - Alert('creativity') - 4 seconds - Alert('html5') - 4 seconds - Alert('EDM') - 4 seconds - ...*

Comment: One important thing about jQuery is when not to use it... There is not need to use it here, and it only caused your troubles. See my answer below. Best wishes.

Answer (score 7):

Move the `setInterval` from the loop.

```
var arr = ['html5', 'EDM', 'Coca Cola', 'creativity'];
var index = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    console.log(arr[index++ % arr.length]);
}, 4000);​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/67ghr/)
No jQuery needed.

Answer (score 4):

Use a recursive `setTimeout`

```
var arr = ['html5', 'EDM', 'Coca Cola', 'creativity'];
var alertLoop = function(i) {
    if (arr[i]) {
        alert(arr[i]);
        setTimeout(function(){alertLoop(i+1);}, 4000);
    }
}
alertLoop(0);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/B5tJw/

Answer (score 1):

Use of `setInterval` is discouraged. For an explanation, read here: http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#other.timeouts

To summarise the problem:

`setInterval` fires the event at a regular interval, regardless of what else is happening on the page.

However, Javascript is not multi-threaded: it can only run one code sequence at a time. If `setInterval` is triggered while another code sequence is being run, the new code sequence will be blocked until the previous one is finished, and will wait for it.

If this happens repeatedly, you can end up with a large number of events waiting to be run.

You're using `alert()` to display your messages. `alert()` causes the code execution sequence to pause until the user responds to the message, but keeps it locked, so that other events cannot run their code. This is a particular problem for `setInterval`, because it fires new events at the specified time, regardless of whether something else is blocking the script.

The solution is to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.

`setTimeout` is only triggered once, but it is easy to tell it to trigger itself again inside its own function, so you can get the same effect as `setInterval`, but with much more control. Your code can wait until after the `alert()` has been accepted by the user before triggering the next event, which means that you won't get the problem of cascading events that can happen with `setInterval`.

Hope that helps explain things. The link I mentioned at the beginning is also very helpful.

Comment: also gets flaky when focus moves to another browser tab and then returns to tab running setInterval