# Display mutliple information one after the other in a looped sequence JQuery - Flapper

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the JQuery plugin Flapper to display a number of names using a single *input* element to create the effect of a split-flap display, as used in train stations etc.

The code I have uses *toggle* which I am guessing only allows two options. I need to be able to display at least 3 names, possibly more.

I am new to Javascript and have been searching but can't figure this one out.
Below is the code I am using.

html

```
<div class="display">
   <input class="header light S" id="header_display" />
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var $header_display = $('#header_display');
           $header_display.flapper({
               width: 16
           });

           setTimeout(function(){
               $header_display.val('INITIAL NAME').change();

               var toggle = false;
           setInterval(function(){
                   if (toggle) {
                       $header_display.val('FIRST NAME').change();          
                   } else {
                       $header_display.val('SECOND NAME').change();          
                   }
                   toggle = !toggle;
               }, 8000);
           }, 700);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to answer my own question, I needed to create an array and then cycle through it one by one. The code from [setInterval with an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876960/setinterval-with-an-array) , particularly AlienWebguy's answer enabled me to achieve it.

The html remained unchanged but the edited Javascript is below.

```
var $header_display = $('#header_display');
            $header_display.flapper({
                width: 16,
            });


            setTimeout(function(){
                $header_display.val('INITIAL NAME').change();

              var arr1 =['SECOND NAME', 'THIRD NAME', 'FOURTH NAME', 'INITIAL NAME'];
              var nameIndex = 0;
            setInterval(function(){
                $header_display.val(arr1[nameIndex++]).change();
                if (nameIndex == arr1.length)
                nameIndex = 0

              }, 8000);
            }, 900);
```